# Fetch data depending by request in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to send the http request what will depend by the button what was clicked. 
So, bellow is my fetch and it is working:

```js
//children component

const Post = (props) => {
    function sendRequestToParrent() {
        props.rRequests("POST")
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={() => {
                sendRequestToParrent();     
            }} type='submit'>POST DATA</Button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Post;

//parent component

    const [variable, setVariable ] = useState(''); // here i set the data from child component which was received with a callback. 


    function rRequests(request) {
        setVariable (request);

            return (
                fetch("URL", {
                    method: `${variable}`,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Accept': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ .... })
                }).then(res => {
                    console.log("response", res);
                })

            )
        }

 return (
        <div>
            <Post rRequests={rRequests} />
           
        </div>
    )
```

The issue appear when i change the method from `method: POST` to `method:`${variable}`. It is possible to add a variable inside method and depending by what value that variable will have, to get the response?

For example: if i will click a button the variable will be equal with "POST", when i will click on another button the variable will be equal with 'DELETE' and depending by this to get the response.

Comment: Did you try adding a parameter for that purpose? What happened?

Comment: I see you are not sending variable to `submit ` function

Comment: @jonrsharpe , appears this error : `Failed to execute 'fetch' '' is not a valid HTTP method. at Object.submit`

Comment: And if you try actually providing a value for the request method? Give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe , the idea of the application is: I have 3 child components. In each compnent i have buttons. When i click on  one of button i send data from child component to parent (here i use a callback). I receive data, but inside submit function, the variable is undefined.

Comment: Need more information.  With the async nature of most callbacks, the way you assign the result to data variable matters.  It would be nice if you can show us every relevant code on how you assign the result to the variable.

Comment: @ProgrammingFreak, i updated the question, there are additional informations

Comment: @jonrsharpe, i updated the question, there are additional informations

Comment: That doesn't make sense. What's the point of variable now? Calling setVariable only changes the value on the *next* render. And string templating a single value that's already a string seems pointless. Why not just `method: request`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic case of the asynchronous nature of setVariable. You are setting the variable and then immediately using it. As the setting of any state happends asynchronously, that is why it is still empty where it being assigned to method. You can directly assign the value of request that you are passing as the parameter to the function.

```js
function rRequests(request) {
        setVariable (request);

            return (
                fetch("URL", {
                    method: `${request}`,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Accept': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ .... })
                }).then(res => {
                    console.log("response", res);
                })

            )
        }
```

You can use the new variable in useEffect hook if you want to

Comment: very straight forward solution!

Answer (score -1):

remove template literal from the method

You need to set the incoming request type from the higher component. "" is showing because of the default parameter you are initiating.

```
const [variable, setVariable ] = useState(''); // here i set the data from child component which was received with a callback. 

setVariable(this.props.method); // method is the parameter name you are passing from the parent component

function submit() {
    return fetch("URL", {
                method: variable,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ .... })
            }).then(res => {
                console.log("response", res);
            });
    }
```

Comment: @S K R, i updated the question, without literals also doesn't work

Comment: @AskMen updated the answer. have a look. method variable is the parameter name you are passing from the parent component.